# iOS Calendar adds wrong day for events for pacific standard time zone

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am trying to add an event to iPhone calendar after booking an event. But it adds the event for same time on the previous day for users in pacific timezone only. Thanks.

```
let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        let localDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from:            session.startDate))
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss a"

        let str = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        print(str)
        
      
        let newStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateFormatter.string(from:
       localDate!))!
        
        calendarEvent.location = eventLocation
        calendarEvent.startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
        calendarEvent.endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!.addingTimeInterval(Double(session.duration) * 60.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never using your constant `newStartDate`.

You have this:

```
 let newStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateFormatter.string(from:
       localDate!))!
        
        calendarEvent.location = eventLocation
        calendarEvent.startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
        calendarEvent.endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: str)!.addingTimeInterval(Double(session.duration) * 60.0)
```

But in the `calendarEvent` configuration you use `str` and you should use `newStartDate` like this:

```
 let newStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from:dateFormatter.string(from:
       localDate!))!
        
        calendarEvent.location = eventLocation
        calendarEvent.startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: newStartDate)
        calendarEvent.endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: newStartDate)!.addingTimeInterval(Double(session.duration) * 60.0)
```